# how to use value that i received from ajax url in yii

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

i am new in yii. i have a form with a combo and a textfield. now i want to change text field value by changing the combo value.
now i get an ajax url by changing combo value and url response is proper i.e. 10 which is my correct value for text field . my problem is that how can i use that value and assign it to that text field. 
my textfiels is:

```
<input id="Subscription_amount" type="text" value="0" name="Subscription[amount]" >
```

my controller code is:

```
public function actiongetSubAmount()
{
    $data=Subscription::model()->findByPk($_POST['sub_id']);
    echo $data->amount;
    exit(); 
}
```

response url i get is from indexController.

Comment: Can you provide code of your controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is not related to php or yii. You need to do such works via javascript or jquery. In the `success` event of ajax request, you can do this:

```
....
success: function(data){
  //data will bee everything you echo in your controller's action
  //in your case, data will be equal to $data->amount
  //if you need to pass an object or a list of object to client, you can use json_encode in your controller and $.parseJson in the view. But in your case don't need to use json, because you have only one data field. 
  $("#Subscription_amount").val(data)
},
```

Comment: but for dropDownList we use like 
$form->dropDownList($model,'id', GxHtml::listDataEx(Model_name::model(  )->findAll(array('condition'=>'id='.$id)),'ai_sync_id','name'),array('prompt'=>'--SELECT--')) and it works....
so what to do in case of textfield?

Comment: I think that is not related to this question, But you can use this for generating text field: $form->textField($model,'fieldName',array('class'=>'className')